# Preciso criar um Arraylist em Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Preciso criar um programa que funcione como uma biblioteca. Eu consegui criar uma parte do programa que cria um livro, dados as informações como parâmetros. Agora preciso criar uma ArrayList que dê para armazenar vários livros, ir adicionando e removendo usando outras funções. Vou mandar o código para criação de um livro, se alguém puder me ajudar, eu agradeço.

```
public class biblioteca {
    public class Livro {
        private String titulo;
        private String autor;
        private short ano;
        private String codigo;
        private boolean disponibilidade;
        ArrayList<Livro> livros;
        

        
        
        public Livro(String novoTitulo, String novoAutor, short novoAno, String novoCodigo, boolean novaDisponibilidade){
            this.titulo = novoTitulo;
            this.autor = novoAutor;
            this.ano = novoAno;
            this.codigo = novoCodigo;
            this.disponibilidade = novaDisponibilidade;
        }
        
      
        }
```

Comment: é estranho por que tem uma lista de livros dentro de sua classe de Livro, provavelmente esse não compila pois não está sendo instanciado também essa lista.

Answer (score -1):

Primeiro separe as duas classes. Uma classe para **Livro** contendo todos os atributos de um livro e uma classe para **Biblioteca** com o atributo

```
ArrayList<Livro> livros = new ArrayList<>();
```

A partir daí basta fazer um livros.add e adicionar um livro novo.

```
    public class Biblioteca {
        private ArrayList<Livro> livros = New ArrayList<>();
        
    //Getter e setters...

        public void addLivro(String novoTitulo, String novoAutor, short novoAno, String novoCodigo, boolean novaDisponibilidade){
            livros.add(new Livro( novoTitulo,  novoAutor,  novoAno,  novoCodigo,  novaDisponibilidade));
       }
     }
```

```
Livro.java

    public class Livro {
        private String titulo;
        private String autor;
        private short ano;
        private String codigo;
        private boolean disponibilidade;

    //Getter e setters

        public Livro(String novoTitulo, String novoAutor, short novoAno, String novoCodigo, boolean novaDisponibilidade){
            this.titulo = novoTitulo;
            this.autor = novoAutor;
            this.ano = novoAno;
            this.codigo = novoCodigo;
            this.disponibilidade = novaDisponibilidade;
        }
    }
```